# Скрипт не работает с подключенным jqueryui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript

Для круговой диаграммы использую waypoints и easypiechart:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    'use strict';
    var $percentChart = $('.monitoring .percent');

    var $barColor = $percentChart.data('bar-color');
    $percentChart.waypoint(function(direction) {
        $percentChart.easyPieChart({
            animate: 1000,
            easing: 'easeOutBounce',
            lineCap: 'square',
            barColor: $barColor,
            trackColor: '#fff',
            scaleColor: '#f0f0f0', 
            size: 69,
            lineWidth: 5
        }) + 'down';
    }, {
            offset: '85%',
            triggerOnce: true
    });
});
```

При подключении jqueryui диаграммы не отображаются. Возможно как-нибудь решить или придется использовать другой скрипт?

Без подключения jqueryui http://arteom.net/demos/waypoints/index.html

с подключенным http://arteom.net/demos/waypoints/indexui.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте актуальные версии скриптов, [easy-pie-chart](https://github.com/rendro/easy-pie-chart) например довольно сильно отличается от той версии которую используете Вы. К тому же на гх даже CanvasRenderer есть. И он более приоритетный чем SVGRenderer. Насколько я понял проблема в нем. Но ничего найти не смог. Попробуйте обновить версию пай-чарта.

Answer (score 0):

Waypoints работает нормально.
Не работает easyPieChart. Канвас с самой диаграммой не отрисовывается.
Попробуйте просто взять другой скрипт для построения диаграмм.

Comment: какой посоветуете?